# Korean is not recognized in HTML page

Tags: html, lang

When I type Korean in my html code and open it through my browser, Korean is not recognized by the browser and prints some weird words. What shall I do?

Comment: Have you set the HTML document's encoding and is the text editor you're using saving the file in the same encoding?

Comment: Google search: html encoding korean

Answer (score 5):

There must be few mistakes you are making.

- **First**, You should have a doctype specified on your HTML page. Use HTML5 doctype

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```
- **Second,** you should specify the character encoding of the document as well. So, add:

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ```

  In your head section. Or for a longer version with better cross browser compatibility use:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
  ```

Also as Juhana said, your file must be saved with same encoding (i.e. Unicode UTF-8) to be able to store Unicode characters and display them.

Comment: This is only half the truth. Setting the document encoding helps only if the file actually uses that encoding.

Comment: @Juhana, Yeah, Adding that to answer.